# I am having problems with a line of ASP code involving response.write

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

Ok folks, I am trying to write a line of code in Classic ASP for a button that will trigger it to go to another page with a querystring variable. However I am having difficulties getting this to work.

Here is my code so far:

```
response.write "<td valign='top'><input type='button' name='cmdUpdateInfo' value='Update Info' tabindex='7' onclick='window.location=updatecustomer.asp?UpdateID=""'" & rs("ID") & "'""/></td>" & vbCrLf
```

When this line is processed I get the following error on my ASP processor:
Error Type:
(0x80020009)
Exception occurred. 
/ls_internal/newinvoice.asp, line 325

line 325 is the line of code above. I know this is something simple, but for the life of me, I cannot seem to figure it out.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So break that down into a minimal test-case. What part is wrong?

Comment: I actually solved it using this code, it make look bad but it works. `code`

response.write "<td valign='top'><input type='button' name='cmdUpdateInfo' value='Update Info' tabindex='3' onclick=" & chr(34) & "location.href=" & chr(39) & "updatecustomer.asp?UpdateID=" & rs("ID") & chr(39) & chr(34) & " />" & vbCrLf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've currently written your line of code it will translate into

```
<td valign='top'><input type='button' name='cmdUpdateInfo' value='Update Info'
tabindex='7' onclick='window.location=updatecustomer.asp?UpdateID="'999'"/></td>
```

Assuming that the rs("id") contains the value 999. There is nothing wrong with that line of  code, first thing I would try doing is comment out the rs("id") element and see if the page runs ok.

If it doesn't then I would check further up your page - are you sure that your SQL query is returning anything? I wonder if your rs is empty (not a NULL value, I mean no records were returned) In which case you need to add an `IF NOT rs.eof THEN` condition to your code.

Personally I would follow Gaby aka G.Petrioli's recommendation above to convert your HTML attributes into double quotes, and JavaScript to single.

Comment: You probably don't meant to pass UpdateID="'999'" to the querystring (more likely you want UpdateID=999)

Comment: Read my comments above for how I ended up solving it. I thank you for your help anyways.

Answer (score 5):

For one you should use double quotes for html attributes and single for javascript so

```
onclick=window.location=updatecustomer.asp?UpdateID=""'" & rs("ID") & "'"" />
```

should be

```
onclick=""window.location='updatecustomer.asp?UpdateID=" & rs("ID") & "'"" />
```

---

Other than that you should output html directly, without having asp handle it as a string to print.

What i mean is that instead of the whole `response.write .....` line you could do

```
%><td valign="top"><input type="button" name="cmdUpdateInfo" value="Update Info" tabindex="7" onclick="window.location='updatecustomer.asp?UpdateID=<%=rs("ID")%>'"/></td>
<%
```

Comment: +1 For the final solution, much better than the horrible Reponse.Write code.  In my experience you end up chasing fewer bugs if you allow HTML/XML attribute values to be placed in " " and Javascript string literals in ' '.  The final approach in this answer acheives that goal and is much easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

As this come inside a loop I prefer to not break out of the ASP code and instead use kind of "template":

```
Dim cellTemplate
cellTemplate = "<td valign=""top""><button type=""button"" name=""cmdUpdateInfo"" tabindex=""7"" onclick=""window.location = 'updatecustomer.asp?UpdateID=$id';"">Update Info</button></td>"

Do Until rs.EOF
    response.write Replace(cellTemplate, "$id", rs("ID")) & vbCrLf
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

This is more elegant and won't create spaghetti code, plus you better use ordinary button and not `<input>` element.